# Count number of rows with the same month

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm new to StackOverflow, so I apologize for bad formatting.

Note: I am using Oracle SQL Developer.

I am trying to convert the below query result:
[image: Query 1]

to something like this:
[image]

Currently what I have in my main SQL works, but it is using sub-queries like so:

```
SELECT distinct(eprdgrp.name)   product_group,
   eprodpkg.name            product_name,
(select count(creation_date) from ECPS_CA 
   where EXTRACT(month from CREATION_DATE)='2'
 AND STATUS='STATUS_NAME'
 AND ABC_CA.ID=ABC_CA.MASTER_ID  
   AND ABC_CA.PROD_PKG_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM ABC_PROD_PKG WHERE NAME=eprodpkg.name))     submission_feb,
   (select count(creation_date) from ABC_CA 
   where EXTRACT(year from CREATION_DATE)=(2016) 
   and EXTRACT(month from CREATION_DATE)='3' 
   AND STATUS='STATUS_NAME'
 AND ABC_CA.ID=ABC_CA.MASTER_ID       
 AND ABC_CA.PROD_PKG_ID IN (SELECT ID FROM ABC_PROD_PKG WHERE NAME=eprodpkg.name))     submission_mar,
...
```

I tried using this code:

```
(select count(eca.creation_date) from dual
   where EXTRACT(month from eca.CREATION_DATE)='2'   
  )     submission_feb,
   (select count(eca.creation_date) from dual
   where EXTRACT(month from eca.CREATION_DATE)='3'   
  )     submission_mar,
```

but it yields different result
[image]

It seems like 1 and 0 is just an indicator of whether there is a result of that product_group, product_name and month combination.

Any help is appreciated and I hope I explained it well enough!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it only February and March or can it be any months of the year?

Comment: It can be any month of the year, these are just examples

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select 
prod_name, name, 
sum(Case when month(creation_date)=2 then 1 else 0 end) as submission_feb,
sum(Case when month(creation_date)=3 then 1 else 0 end) as submission_mar
from ECPS_CA 
group by prod_name, name
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for this:

```
select a.product_group, a.product_name, sum(a.submission_feb) as 
submission_feb, sum(a.submission_mar) as submission_mar
from (
Select product_group, product_name, count(*) as submission_feb, 0 as   
submission_mar
from ECPS_CA
where EXTRACT(month from CREATION_DATE)='2'
group by product_group, product_name
union all
Select product_group, product_name, 0, count(*)
from ECPS_CA
where EXTRACT(month from CREATION_DATE)='3'
group by product_group, product_name
) a
group by a.product_group, a.product_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [PIVOT](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#CHDFAFIE) function in Oracle:

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT prod_group, prod_NAME, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM creation_date) AS creation_month  
    FROM ECPS_CA) 
PIVOT (
    COUNT(*) FOR creation_month IN (
        1 AS SUBMISSION_JAN, 
        2 AS SUBMISSION_FEB, 
        3 AS SUBMISSION_MAR, 
        ... 
        12 AS SUBMISSION_DEC
        )
);
```